# emacs on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-snow-leopard

I am a new iMac user. I have extensive experience with Linux on a PC. I downloaded latest version of emacs to the Applications folder. I want to invoke emacs from the command line. However, the default path for emacs is /usr/bin/emacs. what is the best practice for adding the new emacs to the path? I am tempted to create a ~/bin directory and a link to the new emacs and adding ~/bin to the beginning of my path. This is how we did things in our software development environment on linux PC's

Comment: As an aside, not sure if you're aware, but you can use a subset of emacs shortcuts in pretty much any standard Cocoa app text box, and you can extend them further by defining additional standard keybindings - http://www.gnufoo.org/macosx/

Answer (score 10):

Best way is to use [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) and use

```
brew install emacs --cocoa
```

so you have a easy to update emacs installation. The Cocoa will make sure you have your mac keybinding working before emacs. Make the binary run at startup as a daemon (because it starts up not very fast), for instance:

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/23.2/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --daemon
```

And make an script to the emacsclient command and saved it to /bin/emacs file (don't forget to make it executable):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -n -c "$@"
```

so when you fire up at bash "emacs something.txt" the already running emacs daemon opens it instantly. You can also extend it to open Emacs if the daemon is not running!

I tested it on the latest emacs 23.2, some features are not present on early versions.

Comment: You really shouldn't throw random stuff in `/bin` -- The right thing to do is to either put it earlier in your path or just make aliases for these things.  I use Emacs.app out of the cellar as a normal double-clickable app.

Comment: But if you use bash to edit a random file with emacs it opens another Emacs. My emacs script actually is on my ~/bin. Sometimes you have to manually set the bin as on: make EMACS=<path to actual emacs bin> if it depends on the actual bin file. 99% of the time you won't notice the diference.

Comment: I personally don't think homebrew is the easiest way to install cocoa emacs when you could download a prebuilt .dmg file from http://emacsformacosx.com/builds and drag it into your applications like any other OS X application.

Comment: Homebrew would be the right way to install emacs if (and only if) adamv would pull his head out and [allow emacs to defualt to GUI when complied for GUI](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16638) like it does on *every other platform*.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you were still in linux land, wouldn't the canonical place to put this be in `/usr/local/bin` (and add that to your path?) ... I'd stick with that, if you were to go that route, but this is how I have my emacs setup:

1. I've downloaded the latest plain/vanilla Emacs from [emacsforosx.com](http://emacsformacosx.com/)
2. I've made an `emacs` alias that I use to fire up a terminal-based version of emacs when I don't want (or can't) run the GUI version, like so:

   `alias emacs='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw'`
3. If you want to fire up the GUI version of Emacs from the terminal, you can just type the following (which, AFAIK, is a mac-ism, so you wouldn't have known that coming from linux):

   `$ open -a Emacs`

Answer (score 6):

There's a slew of information about [emacs on OS X](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS) at the [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/).

`~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` will work fine, as will manipulating your `PATH`.

Assuming you're using Emacs.app, simplest thing to do is to use `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app "$@"`.  `open` is the command line equivalent of double-clicking on something in Finder.  Put that into a shell script, stick it into your PATH and go.

Installing `emacs-app` via [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) is probably the simplest way to get and maintain a Cocoa emacs.

You may wish to look into [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) which is a further refinement of emacs for OS X.  The [emacs wiki page on Aquamacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsEmacs) is very helpful.  It also has an option to add a little aquamacs script to your PATH that will open a file in the aquamacs GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I create a shell script named emacs in my ~/bin directory containing:

```
open -a Emacs "$@"
```

Obviously, ~/bin needs to be before /usr/bin in my PATH which I set in ~/.profile so that it shadows the preinstalled emacs binary.

I also create a symlink via `ln -s /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient ~/bin/emacsclient` so that this also shadows the preinstalled emacsclient binary.

For additional connivence, I create an alias ec='emacsclient -a emacs -n ' and include (server-start) in my emacs init scripts.  This enables me to open a file from the commandline using ec filename regardless if emacs is or is not already running.

Another tip: When you launch the emacs via Applications or open, emacs does not inherit the same path as you have in your terminal environment, so one thing I have found very useful is to run the following in my .profile after setting my path to change the PATH inherited cocoa applications:

```
   defaults write ${HOME}/.MacOSX/environment PATH "$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

That will work.  If this is a native mac application, the binary is actually located under the application directory (not the capitalization of the binary):  *...*/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs

Since you are coming from linux, you might be interested in [MacPorts](http://macports.org).  This is a large collection of packages ported from linux.  It allows packages to be installed and upgraded from the command line, doe sdependancy management, all the stuff you would expect.  It includes a native version of Emacs, that can be invoked from the command line.